# Average number of electrons per atom in a given state, given a thermal distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

Im struggling with a question that I saw online.
It is the following:

An atom has 2 electron-states (which are not degenerate) with energies $ \varepsilon_{1},\varepsilon_{2} $.

In the room temperature (300K), the average number of electrons per atom in state 1 is 0.5. What is the average number of electrons per atom in state 2?

Im not sure what exactly is the "average number of electrons per atom", how can we calculate it using the Fermi-Dirac distribution?

(I do not need a solution, just a guidance and maybe explanation of the way to calculate the average number of electrons per atom).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the electron energies explicitly?

Comment: @franz I know, but I didnt mention the exact value because I want fo find a general result in terms if $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elctron distribution function $f(E)$ determines to which extend the electronic state with energy E is occupied.
In your case Fermi-Dirac statistics apply, so we know the exact functional context.
The Fermi-Dirac distribution function is given as
\begin{equation}
f(E) = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{E-\mu}{k_{\mathrm{B}}T}} + 1}
\end{equation}
, where $\mu$ is the chemical potential, $k_{\mathrm{B}}$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ the temperature.

You state that your electronic state $\varepsilon_1$ is occupied by $0.5$. Therefore you can straight-forward deduct $\mu = \varepsilon_1$.
The occupation of the second electronic state is thus given by
\begin{equation}
f(\varepsilon_2) = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{\varepsilon_2-\varepsilon_1}{k_{\mathrm{B}}T}} + 1} \quad.
\end{equation}

Adding up both of these values, leaves you with the total number of electrons located at the atom.

Edit: You might need to multiply your result by a factor of two, as in the case of spin-degenerate bands, 2 electrons find place at one electronic energy. So a half-filled (spin-degenerate) band, would actually correspond to 1 electron.

Comment: I understand that $ f\left(\varepsilon_{2}\right) $ is the probability that the energy $\varepsilon_2 $ is occupied, can you please explain why does it is also the number of average electrons per atom?

Comment: The number of particles at a given time $t$ can be definded by the position and momentum integral over the electron distribution function $f(\vec{r}, \vec{k}, t)$. In your case there is no $\vec{r}$, $\vec{k}$ and $t$ dependence, as you consider an isolated atom. So the total number of electrons, located at your single atom is just the sum of the occupied electronic levels $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$, i.e. $f(\varepsilon_1) + f(\varepsilon_2)$.

Comment: *Fermi-Dirac statics* or *Fermi-Dirac statistics*?

Comment: Could we show it alternatively using $ N=\intop g\left(\varepsilon\right)f_{FD}\left(\varepsilon\right)d\varepsilon $ ? Isnt it the expression for  the numbers of electrons?

Comment: thank you @Gert, I corrected the typo.

Comment: @FreeZe, correct. but what is the density of states $g(\varepsilon)$ in your case?

Comment: @franz Im not sure actually, and Im also not sure if the $N$ is the number of electrons per atom or  per unit volume

Comment: @FreeZe depends on the definition of $g(\varepsilon)$, which is mostly normalized to unit volume. But in your case the density of states is simple. Density of states just gives the number of electronic states, that you can fill with electrons. As your atom only has two energy-levels, you will have two (or four) states, that you can put your electrons into, considering non-degenerate (or spin-degenerate) energy-levels.